# Array allocates space for more elements than requested

Tags: c++

When I execute the following code, **c_copy** is initialized with more elements than specified by **sz**, what is causing this behavior? I thought that perhaps it was happening because arrays required a constant value, but declaring a constant value in or outside of the method did not help.

```
char* e4_strdup( const char*& c )
{
    unsigned int sz{ 0 };
    for ( const char* p_to_c = c; *p_to_c != '\0'; ++p_to_c )
        ++sz;

    char* c_copy{ new char[ sz ] };
    for ( unsigned int i{ 0 }; i < sz; ++i )
        c_copy[ i ] = c[ i ];

    return c_copy;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I am determining the number of elements that were allocated by stepping through the program.

Also, when I output the returned pointer through std::cout, it prints more than the original input c-string.

**EDIT 2:**
The fixed code.

```
char* e4_strdup( const char*& c )
{
    unsigned int sz{ 0 };
    for ( const char* p_to_c = c; *p_to_c != '\0'; ++p_to_c )
        ++sz;

    char* c_copy{ new char[ ++sz ] }; // extra space for '\0' character.
    for ( unsigned int i{ 0 }; i < sz; ++i )
        c_copy[ i ] = c[ i ];

    return c_copy;
}
```

Comment: How are you determining the number of elements that were allocated?

Comment: Why not `std::vector` and `std::copy?`

Comment: Because it's an exercise on pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not allocating more space - you're simply failing to copy the trailing `\0`, so when you print the string it's continuing past the end of what you've officially allocated. Welcome to the world of undefined behavior.

P.S. You need to allocate space for the trailing `\0` before you copy it, you're not doing that either.

Comment: It's so obvious now that you've told me. Thank you.